# How can I fix this? I'm not able to access the data received?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, I did a post method, but im not able to access the following codee

```
{"responses":[{"labelAnnotations":[{"mid":"/m/03q69","description":"Hair","score":0.98823804,"topicality":0.98823804},{"mid":"/m/0dzct","description":"Face","score":0.9831542,"topicality":0.9831542},{"mid":"/m/025kyy","description":"Forehead","score":0.95435387,"topicality":0.95435387},{"mid":"/m/0f9swq","description":"Chin","score":0.9088191,"topicality":0.9088191},{"mid":"/m/0ds4x","description":"Hairstyle","score":0.90202826,"topicality":0.90202826},{"mid":"/m/04hgtk","description":"Head","score":0.9014164,"topicality":0.9014164},{"mid":"/m/027n3_","description":"Eyebrow","score":0.89324903,"topicality":0.89324903},{"mid":"/m/0ds5b","description":"Facial hair","score":0.87170535,"topicality":0.87170535},{"mid":"/m/037p5b","description":"Cheek","score":0.8612985,"topicality":0.8612985},{"mid":"/m/0k0pj","description":"Nose","score":0.8419632,"topicality":0.8419632}]}]}
```

I did for example

```
for(let item of data_recieved){
  console.log(item.response.decription)
}
```

I get an error, I'm trying to get descrpition so I can use it

Comment: have you parsed data as json?  `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: also, check for type mistakes!

Comment: Hello mark could you show how did you do the post request ?

Answer (score 1):

Your data is more complex than just an array.  `data_recieved` has a property called `responses`, which is an array, the first item of which has a property called `labelAnnotations`, which is an array, the items of which have the values you want.

So it would be something like this:

```js
let data_recieved = {"responses":[{"labelAnnotations":[{"mid":"/m/03q69","description":"Hair","score":0.98823804,"topicality":0.98823804},{"mid":"/m/0dzct","description":"Face","score":0.9831542,"topicality":0.9831542},{"mid":"/m/025kyy","description":"Forehead","score":0.95435387,"topicality":0.95435387},{"mid":"/m/0f9swq","description":"Chin","score":0.9088191,"topicality":0.9088191},{"mid":"/m/0ds4x","description":"Hairstyle","score":0.90202826,"topicality":0.90202826},{"mid":"/m/04hgtk","description":"Head","score":0.9014164,"topicality":0.9014164},{"mid":"/m/027n3_","description":"Eyebrow","score":0.89324903,"topicality":0.89324903},{"mid":"/m/0ds5b","description":"Facial hair","score":0.87170535,"topicality":0.87170535},{"mid":"/m/037p5b","description":"Cheek","score":0.8612985,"topicality":0.8612985},{"mid":"/m/0k0pj","description":"Nose","score":0.8419632,"topicality":0.8419632}]}]};

if (data_recieved.responses.length > 0) {
    for (let item of data_recieved.responses[0].labelAnnotations) {
        console.log(item.description);
    }
}
```

Note: You also mis-spelled `description` in your `console.log` statement.

Comment: @mark the most efficient way to thanks someone who answers you on SO is by accepting his answer by clicking on the check mark button. Accept this answer if this helped you out.

Comment: I'm trying its not letting me , also I tried printing item.descrtipion its not working?

Comment: @mark: Because there's no property called `descrtipion`.  Spelling the property names correctly is important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` loops for doing this. The first `forEach` loop will access the array corresponding to `responses` and the second `forEach` will correspond to the array associated with `labelAnnotations` array in which the description resides.

```js
var a={"responses":[{"labelAnnotations":[{"mid":"/m/03q69","description":"Hair","score":0.98823804,"topicality":0.98823804},{"mid":"/m/0dzct","description":"Face","score":0.9831542,"topicality":0.9831542},{"mid":"/m/025kyy","description":"Forehead","score":0.95435387,"topicality":0.95435387},{"mid":"/m/0f9swq","description":"Chin","score":0.9088191,"topicality":0.9088191},{"mid":"/m/0ds4x","description":"Hairstyle","score":0.90202826,"topicality":0.90202826},{"mid":"/m/04hgtk","description":"Head","score":0.9014164,"topicality":0.9014164},{"mid":"/m/027n3_","description":"Eyebrow","score":0.89324903,"topicality":0.89324903},{"mid":"/m/0ds5b","description":"Facial hair","score":0.87170535,"topicality":0.87170535},{"mid":"/m/037p5b","description":"Cheek","score":0.8612985,"topicality":0.8612985},{"mid":"/m/0k0pj","description":"Nose","score":0.8419632,"topicality":0.8419632}]}]}

a.responses.forEach((e)=>e.labelAnnotations.forEach((x)=>console.log(x.description)))
```

Comment: Uhhm none are working for mee. can you please do it in a different way